# pandas dataframe group by create a new column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe with the below format:

```
name         date           
Anne         2018/07/04 
Anne         2018/07/06
Bob          2015/10/01
Bob          2015/10/10
Bob          2015/11/11
Anne         2018/07/05
...          ...
```

I would like to add a column which is a relative number of days passed from the minimum date of the person.

for each row:

```
relative_day = (person's date) - (minimum of person's date)
```

The output is:

```
name         date           relative_day     
Anne         2018/07/04     0
Anne         2018/07/04     2
Bob          2015/10/01     0
Bob          2015/10/01     9
Bob          2015/11/11     41
Anne         2018/07/05     1
```

I tried to groupby name first and then writing a for loop over each name and add a column but it gives the error of

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
df['relative_day'] = None
person_groups = df.groupby('name')
for person_name, person_dates in person_groups:
    person_dates['relative_day'] = person_dates['date'].min()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['new'] = (df.date - df.groupby('name').date.transform('min')).dt.days
df
   name       date  new
0  Anne 2018-07-04    0
1  Anne 2018-07-06    2
2   Bob 2015-10-01    0
3   Bob 2015-10-10    9
4   Bob 2015-11-11   41
5  Anne 2018-07-05    1
```

Comment: Thank you your solution works perfectly! Just a follow up question on this, how can I get the relative hours instead of days?

Answer (score 2):

Get the name as an index, group on the name, then subtract the minimum to get your relative dates.

```
result = df.astype({"date": np.datetime64}).set_index("name")
result.assign(relative_day=result['date'] - result.groupby("name")['date'].transform("min"))
         date   relative_day
name        
Anne    2018-07-04  0 days
Anne    2018-07-06  2 days
Bob     2015-10-01  0 days
Bob     2015-10-10  9 days
Bob     2015-11-11  41 days
Anne    2018-07-05  1 days
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: what line is triggering the error? Check your dtypes, the date should be in datetime format

Comment: I have other coloumns as well. I think that might be the issue

Comment: that's the catch. try it with the data you shared and see if it works. Also edited the solution, see if that fits

Comment: It works, but how can I keep the other columns as is?

Answer (score 1):

[@sammywemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649025/13106495) has a good solution. I want to show another possible way.

```py
import pandas as pd 

# read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# change column data type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

# group by name
df_group = df.groupby('name')

# get minimum date value
df_group_min = df_group['date'].min()

# create minimum date column by name
df['min'] = df.apply(lambda r: df_group_min[r['name']], axis=1)

# calculate relative day
df['relative_day'] = (df['date'] - df['min']).dt.days

# remove minimum column
df.drop('min', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output

```
   name       date  relative_day
0  Anne 2018-07-04             0
1  Anne 2018-07-06             2
2   Bob 2015-10-01             0
3   Bob 2015-10-10             9
4   Bob 2015-11-11            41
5  Anne 2018-07-05             1
```

Comment: Thank you your solution works perfectly! Just a follow-up question on this, how can I get the relative hours instead of days?

Comment: @Anne you can use `total_seconds` method transform it into hours. `df['relative_hours'] = (df['date'] - df['min']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600`